# ASP.NET C# Sessions SessionID changes on Page_Load()

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, sessionid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET: Session.SessionID changes between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874078/asp-net-session-sessionid-changes-between-requests)

I find this very weird, I'm still new to C# and ASP.NET Framework however i dont understand why on each `Page_Load()` execution my `Session` is assigned a diffirent SessionID.

My understanding is that when a Client opens my Application he is assigned a Session shouldn't the SessionID stay the same until said session expires and shouldnt change if user refreshes the Page.

All i have is:

```
Page_Load()
{
    Response.Write((String) Session.SessioID);
}
```

And each time i refresh the page it prints out a diffirent SessionID

Comment: Reminder: Please make sure to post valid code.

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled?

Comment: WHO votes up a duplicate question? Oh dear...