# Session Id change in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

Suppose I have 2 user, "user-1" and "user-2" using 2 computer "comp-1" and "comp-2" respectively.
The "user-1" do some task and reload the page and on the other side the "user-2" is doing some work after some time the "user-2" change reload the page got that the session state of the "user-2" change to "user-1".

I think this the problem of session overlapping, i tried a lot of ways but can't meet any solution.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sessions are unique to each session. If they are serving from the same computer, you will be fine. Show some code to identify the problem. It may well be a problem with your code.

Comment: Clearly you are performing your own session management. The way in which you're performing that is *imperative* to this question. Session overlap is not possible in ASP.NET when using the default session management.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your session variable. Take a look at that post for details:

[ASP.NET: Session.SessionID changes between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874078/asp-net-session-sessionid-changes-between-requests)