# Don't redirect after setting a Session variable

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect

I'm facing a problem when redirecting to a page.
Please have a look at my code and how i may solve it.
The manifest is that after saving variables in session and redirect to a new page, the session variables are lost, and a new sessionId is created. 
I am a novice. Please advice.

Login.aspx:

```
Util.IsAdminUser= false; // save in session Util.IsAdminUser
Util.IsSpecialUser = true; //save in session Util.IsSpecialUser
Response.Redirect(Pages.SelectAccounts, false);
return;
```

SelectAccounts.aspx:

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Util.IsAdminUser)  // error of null, session is lost
    {
       ...
       ...
    }
   }
 protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             LoggerNet.Info("SessionId:" + Session.SessionID); 
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: how do you store your session? Can you show the `Util` class and `CheckSessionExpired();` method?

Comment: In Util i set Session["IsAdmin"] = false, Session["IsSpecialUser"]=true. Anyway..i am guessing that is a problem with saving the data in session and redirecting.. i don't know what cause this behaviour and what are the good practice..

Comment: how do you store your session? InProc, SQL, etc.

Comment: saving the session in SQL

Comment: `In Util i set Session["IsAdmin"] = false` According to your comment, the result'll always be **false**. Please add the actual code of `Util.IsAdminUser`.

Answer (score 1):

According the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx):

> For mobile pages, if your application relies on cookieless sessions, 
>   or might receive requests from mobile devices that require cookieless 
>   sessions, using a tilde `(~)` in a path **can create a new session and 
>   potentially lose session data**.
>
> To set a property on a mobile control
>   with a path such as `~/path`, resolve the path using `ResolveUrl`
>   `~/path` before assigning it to the property.

So, if you have a `~` in your `Pages.SelectAccounts` constant, you may have a new Session each time. Try to add the [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method before the redirect.
May be you should switch to the [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx) method, which is perform similar action, but without the roundtrip to the client. Please refer to the MSDN for more information:

[How to: Redirect Users to Another Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx.aspx)
[Correct use of System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx)

---

**Update**

Also you should check this answer:

[ASP.NET: Session.SessionID changes between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874078/asp-net-session-sessionid-changes-between-requests/2874174#2874174)

Try to use the `Session` object in your `Global.asax` file for handling the `Session_Start` event - this will lock the `SessionId` for current user, and it wouldn't be changed again.

---

**Update #2**:

You **must** set some variable into the `Session` object, like this:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoggerNet.Info("SessionId:" + Session.SessionID);
    Session["LastVisitDate"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Only after **setter** for the `Session` object is being called you'll have the persistent `SessionId` for the user.

Comment: I already have Session_Start event and i'm not using cookiesless session or mobile pages

Comment: @user2483797 Can you provide the `Session_Start` code? Do you use the setter for the Session object in it?

Comment: Updated, please have a look

Comment: @user2483797, Yes, I saw it. You don't call any setters for the `Session`, so this object will be a new one each time you call the new page. Try to store there some information. Otherwise I don't know why it doesn't work.