# HttpContext.Current.Items["value"] not working because AngularJS calls create new sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm using C#, MVC and AngularJS.

My problem is that my MVC program creates a `HttpContext.Current.Items["value"]` and sets the value in the initial home controller, but when my AngularJS hits the application with an ajax call, it creates a new session and I can't get the value I set earlier in my `HttpContext.Current.Items["value"]` call.

Is there something I can do to fix this problem? I'd like to continue using `HttpContext.Current.Items["value"]`.

Why do my AngularJS calls create new sessionids?  The reason I know the sessions are new is because they have different ids when I use this:

```
String strSessionId = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
```

Comment: The scope of `HttpContext.Current.Items` is the current request only.

Comment: shouldn't HttpContext.Current.Items be able accessible on a users session.  I guess my problem is my angularjs calls are creating new sessions and I don't know why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Items` is a dictionary for request caching only. As soon as the request is finished all of the values in it will go out of scope.

```
// Will last until the end of the current request
HttpContext.Current.Items["key"] = value;

// When the request is finished, the value can no longer be retrieved
var value = HttpContext.Current.Items["key"];
```

`HttpContext.Current.Session` is a dictionary that stores data between requests.

```
// Will be stored until the user's session expires
HttpContext.Current.Session["key"] = value;

// You can retrieve the value again in the next request, 
// until the session times out.
var value = HttpContext.Current.Session["key"];
```

The reason why your `HttpRequest.Current.Items` value is not available again is because you are setting it "in your home controller", which is a completely separate request from your AJAX call.

Session state depends on a cookie, so if the same cookie is sent back to the server, the data stored there can be retrieved. Fortunately, if you are on the same domain, [AJAX will automatically send the cookie back to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie).

As for the SessionID changing, [ASP.NET does not allocate storage for session until it is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874078/asp-net-session-sessionid-changes-between-requests). So you need to explicitly store something in session state in order to actually start a session. See [this MSDN article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918) for more information.