# MVC send data from view to httpcontext class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

i tried this but dose not work

```
  @{ 
         HttpContext.Current.Items["key"] = Reservation.ConfirmationFilename;

  }
```

and this is context

```
 public class DownloadFile : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {


         //here file name is null 

        string fileName = (string)(HttpContext.Current.Items["key"]);

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        context.Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is `filename` is null after i assign the value to it .
any advice to send data from view to `httpcontext`

Comment: executed when button click to download file

Comment: The answer on this possible duplicate will help...  [HttpContext.Current.Items\["value"\] not working because AngularJS calls create new sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814034/httpcontext-current-itemsvalue-not-working-because-angularjs-calls-create-ne)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]` or `TempData["key"]` ?