# ASP.NET not sending session cookie

Tags: asp.net, session, session-cookies

What would cause ASP.NET to not send a session cookie to the client?

I've noticed that, first of all, "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie is set in both the `Request.Cookies` and `Response.Cookies` collections.  Interestingly, the cookie was not actually part of the request, but the `Request.Cookies` collection seems to be a dynamic combination of cookies actually sent with the request and cookies in the response.  So if you add a cookie to the `Response.Cookies` collection, it will be immediately be reflected in the `Request.Cookies` collection.

Anyway.... the cookie is definitely in the `Response.Cookies` collection.  You can even get it in there twice by calling `new SessionIDManager().SaveSessionID(HttpContext.Current, HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID, out redirected, out cookieAdded)`, and cookieAdded will return true and there will now be two entries named "ASP.NET_SessionId" instead of one.

But the cookie is never sent with the response.  What code or set of conditions decides to not send the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie with the response even though it's in the `Response.Cookies` collection?

The conditions I have right now that seem to be triggering it is that I have my MVC base controller marked as `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]`, which is necessary in order for multiple simultaneously AJAX requests to be processed in parallel by ASP.NET MVC; otherwise, it considers session a shared state and serializes processing of requests under the same session id.  Since I"m not storing data in the "real" session which is marked as read-only, I'm actually storing session data in a static location and managing concurrency myself, but I'm still using the ASP.NET-generated SessionID to track it (clever, eh?).  Problem is, without the cookie being sent, the SessionID is changing with every new request, so I lose track of the user's session every time.  I cannot seem to force the system to send the cookie; something is intentionally not sending it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2874174/88409

Answer (score 0):

This causes from the behavior of SessionStateModule.
SessionStateModule sets the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie in the Response.Cookies collections in AcquireRequestState event when "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie is not sent from the client. Then if nothing is stored in the session, SessionStateModule deletes the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie in ReleaseRequestState event. If you set the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie in the Response.Cookies collections manually and nothing is stored, then SessionStateModule deletes all the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookies including the cookie you set.

If you want to track the client, you should use a cookie with a name other than "ASP.NET_SessionId" or add "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie manually after ReleaseRequestState event.