# Session is always null when redirect to another page? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I tried to add session and then i accessed on another page after redirect this always show null

```
Session.Add("pUser_Name", ds_1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["User_Name"].ToString());
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.Redirect("DashBoard.aspx", false);
```

here on another page i am accessing like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Session["pUser_Name"] == null)  ////here is error NULL
     {

         Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
     }
 }
```

I tried

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["pUser_Name"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
    }
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

and also

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DashBoard.aspx.cs" Inherits="SC.DashBoard" EnableTheming="true"
Theme="Theme1" EnableSessionState="True" %>
```

and Admin page where assigning value to session

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableSessionState="True" CodeBehind="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="SC.Admin" %>
```

and web.config file

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
   <sessionState timeout="12000"/>
</system.web>
```

but still facing same session is null

Comment: just for a try instead of `Session.Add` use `HttpContext.Current.Session.Add` and access like `HttpContext.Current.Session["pUser_Name"]`

Comment: same problem still not resolved

Comment: Update panel also not resolve issue..

Comment: Just to be clear, what is null? Is it Session or Session["pUser_name"]?

Comment: note that if your page is loaded from returning back and callback from external gateway or application it have different requester and different session id

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874078/asp-net-session-sessionid-changes-between-requests/2874174#2874174) which basically refers to this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx) about `SessionID`, you might need to initialise your session object on **Session_Start**:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["init"] = 0;
}
```

This is required when session state is stored in a cookie, which you currently use based on your web.config. The reason is that ASP.NET does not save session up until its first usage and as a result a new SessionID is generated with each **new** page request which is happening when you `Response.Redirect` to another page.