# Global asax Session_End not fired when session lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables, global-asax

I am doing ajax call to asp.net mvc action(it is name SearchResults action)

In SearchResults action I set a session

```
context.Session["FlightSearchRequest"] = flightSearchRequest;
```

and then Redirect To another Action

```
return RedirectToAction("GetAvailableFlights");
```

In GetAvailableFlights action I want to access session

```
return context.Session["FlightSearchRequest"] as FlightSearchRequest;
```

But it is null

I think my session lost but why?I want to debug this

I added

```
  protected void Session_End(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {   
        }
```

to global.asax but it is not fired...When my session get null I want catch this what should I do ?

Comment: Is 'context.Session' the same as just 'Session'?

Comment: yes,it worked in another project with different action @feihoa

Comment: Not sure, but try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299680/session-is-always-null-when-redirect-to-another-page-c-sharp