# Mobile browser starts a new session on each request

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I created asp.net site. Everything goes well when I am browsing the site on my desktop. But when I open my site on my Iphone - Chrome browser, every request seems to start a new session. I am using the Session.SessionId as associate to shopping cart. But its useles when I get new session on every request...

What I am missing?

New info: I tested one think... when I set sessionState cookieless="true" then it work on my mobile phone. BUT it ruins my URLs! So it seems to be problem with cookies. Is there another way to identify people? I am using SessionId as a shopping cart identificator.

Comment: Where is the site hosted? In local IIS on your desktop? How does your iPhone connect to the web server? Can you share some code?

Comment: Hi, website is hosted in hosting provider. New info: I tested one think... when I set sessionState cookieless="true" then it work on my mobile phone. BUT it ruins my URLs. So it seems to be problem with cookies. Is there another way to identify people? I am using SessionId as a shopping cart identificator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. Big thanks to Claudio Redi! I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874078/asp-net-session-sessionid-changes-between-requests?answertab=votes#tab-to)

> When using cookie-based session state, ASP.NET does not allocate
> storage for session data until the Session object is used. As a
> result, a new session ID is generated for each page request until the
> session object is accessed. If your application requires a static
> session ID for the entire session, you can either implement the
> Session_Start method in the application's Global.asax file and store
> data in the Session object to fix the session ID, or you can use code
> in another part of your application to explicitly store data in the
> Session object.

And thank to all who tried to help me :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

see your web.config,
maybe session colsed, like

```
    <sessionState mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: Hi session state is on, see updated topic on the top.