# How do I get a session by SessionID in C#

Tags: c#, session, uploadify

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app and I'm trying to use the 'Uploadify' JQuery plugin.  One issue I'm running into is that there is apparently a well known bug in regards to sending up cookie information with Flash (which uploadify utilizes).  So I've tried sending the auth token and the session id with my request when uploading a file using uploadify.  This is great in that I can figure out if someone is authorized, but I can't seem to get the session and thus do not have access to session variables.  If I have the SessionID, is there a way to get the Session in C#?

Comment: You should mark some answers as accepted in your other questions

Comment: I think that's fair, Jimmy, except that a lot of the answers are either not quite right or I have not tested them yet.  For example, this very question was misunderstood.  Either I didn't write it correctly, or it was hurriedly read through.  As a result, it does not have the correct answer.  In that case, it would be inappropriate of me to mark it as correct for it helps no one who has the same problem.  It's not that I don't appreciate the time of those who assist others, but I want to make sure I only mark answers that are correct and assist others.

Answer (score 2):

```
Session["myVar"] = "1234";
<%= this.Session.SessionID %>

HttpContext.Session.SessionID
```

Note that you can get the session ID, but you need to store things in the temp data or it will keep giving you new IDs.

[This post has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281881/sessionid-keeps-changing-in-asp-net-mvc-why)

Comment: I already know how to get the session ID.  What I want to know is this: "If I have the SessionID, is there a way to get the Session in C#?"