# Display Model Errors in ChildAction Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 Partial views in my ParentView and I am loading partial views like this:

```
Html.RenderAction("Action1WithChildView1")
Html.RenderAction("Action2WithChildView2")
```

Each child views has own Form and Submit button.

```
if child1 submitted to an 
    public RedirectToRouteResult Child1ActionPost() {
    Check for model state and add some model errors,Then
    RedirectToAction(ParentActionReturingMainview);
    }

if child2 submitted to an 
    public RedirectToRouteResult Child2ActionPost() {
    Check for model state and add some model errors,Then
    RedirectToAction(ParentActionReturingMainview);
    }
```

I have a Validation Summary in each child View, but it is not displaying Model Errors associated with the child views.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642845/asp-net-mvc-how-to-preserve-modelstate-errors-across-redirecttoaction check this ,might help

Comment: No,My ParentView has seperate model and also ChildView called from Parent View using RenderAction.So it will not maintain/passs model state to child action.