# return View() not working inside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC C#.  I have my view with the following line of code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TastingParty", "Contact"))
```

I am submitting to a different controller and action than the current page is on so I had to add a custom controller and action in that line.  Now it gets to my controller and at the bottom of the method I call "return View();" so it will display the same page again.  But it is looking for that view in the Contact controller because that is where I sent it.

How do I return the original View that it came from?  Hopefully that all makes sense.

Comment: you need to `return RedirectToAction(...)` and put the Action/Controller pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return RedirectToAction(Action,Controler)
```

You are searching for this?

Comment: Should this be displaying my validation errors like "return View()" does?  Because I'm not seeing any errors when it comes back.

Comment: So it appears like this method loses my ModelState.  Hmmmmm....  I'm reading through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642845/asp-net-mvc-how-to-preserve-modelstate-errors-across-redirecttoaction

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `return RedirectToAction(...`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Or, if you want to be able to reuse the view across different controllers, you can place it in the `Views\Shared` folder.

In the latter case, you then have the ability to return the posted model back out to that view.

```
public ActionResult YourAction(YourViewModel postedModel) {

    // do something

    return View(postedModel);
}
```

And again, if you want this to be a shared view, you could place it under `Views\Shared\YourAction.cshtml`.