# How to keep using ModelState with RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a method to remove the object. Removal does not own view, and is a "Delete" button in the "EditReport". Upon successful removal of a redirect on "Report".

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{reportId:int}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult DeleteReport(int reportId)
{
    var success = _reportService.DeleteReportControl(reportId);
    if (success == false)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Messages");
        return RedirectToAction("EditReport");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("OK", "Messages");
    return RedirectToAction("Report");
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC 5 I use the following attributes to save ModelState between methods. I took from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024227/3878213

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);         
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["ModelState"] = 
           filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
    }
}

public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.Controller.TempData.ContainsKey("ModelState"))
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(
                (ModelStateDictionary)filterContext.Controller.TempData["ModelState"]);
        }
    }
}
```

But in ASP.NET MVC 6 RC 1 (ASP.NET Core 1.0), this code does not work.

Error in filterContext.Controller does not contain definitions for TempData and ViewData.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35981780/3878213), I realized that the need to create your own code ASP.NET Core 1.0 (Full .NET Framework 4.6.2)

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        var modelState = controller?.ViewData.ModelState;
        if (modelState != null)
        {
            var listError = modelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any())
                .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors
                .Select(s => s.ErrorMessage)
                .FirstOrDefault(s => s != null));
            controller.TempData["ModelState"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listError);
        }
    }
}
public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        var tempData = controller?.TempData?.Keys;
        if (controller != null && tempData != null)
        {
            if (tempData.Contains("ModelState"))
            {
                var modelStateString = controller.TempData["ModelState"].ToString();
                var listError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(modelStateString);
                var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
                foreach (var item in listError)
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError(item.Key, item.Value ?? "");
                }

                controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Asynchronous version of the code ASP.NET Core 1.0 (Full .NET Framework 4.6.2)

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(filterContext, next);

            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            var modelState = controller?.ViewData.ModelState;
            if (modelState != null)
            {
                var listError = modelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any())
                    .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors
                    .Select(s => s.ErrorMessage)
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s != null));
                var listErrorJson = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listError));
                controller.TempData["ModelState"] = listErrorJson;
            }
            await next();
        }
    }
public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(filterContext, next);

            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            var tempData = controller?.TempData?.Keys;
            if (controller != null && tempData != null)
            {
                if (tempData.Contains("ModelState"))
                {
                    var modelStateString = controller.TempData["ModelState"].ToString();
                    var listError = await Task.Run(() => 
                        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(modelStateString));
                    var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
                    foreach (var item in listError)
                    {
                        modelState.AddModelError(item.Key, item.Value ?? "");
                    }

                    controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
                }
            }
            await next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There should be a check to prevent non-errors from showing up in `SetTempDataModelStateAttribute` line `var listError = modelState.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors` should be `modelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()).ToDictionary(m...`

Comment: Using `await next();` is incorrect here as it causes that method to be hit multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

The fix to make the code compile is below, but it appears that ASP.NET Core does not support serializing the model state (due to `ModelStateEntry` containing exceptions which are never serializable).

As such, you cannot serialize the model state in `TempData`. And as explained in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4190), there appear to be no plans to change this behavior.

---

The `Controller` property in `ActionExecutingContext` is of type `object`. This is because controllers in ASP.NET Core are not required to inherit from `Controller`, so there is no common base type for them.

In order to access the `TempData` property, you have to cast it to `Controller` first. Your attributes could look like this then:

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            controller.TempData["ModelState"] = controller.ViewData.ModelState;
        }
    }
}

public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null & controller.TempData.ContainsKey("ModelState"))
        {
            controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(
                (ModelStateDictionary)controller.TempData["ModelState"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add to Sessions project. While I can not solve the problem with the error: `InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.SessionStateTempDataProvider' cannot serialize an object of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary' to session state`.

Comment: It appears that ASP.NET Core does not support serializing the model state, and there are no plans to change that. I’ve updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: properly will convert ModelState in string (json) and store in TempData?

Comment: You can’t serialize the model state, that includes serializing it as JSON. If you still want to do that, you will have to serialize it manually.

Comment: thanks for the info. Here is my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/35987804/3878213

Comment: Sorry, comment removed