# Async using ModelState with RedirectToAction in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a method to remove the object. Removal does not own view, and is a "Delete" button in the "EditReport". Upon successful removal of a redirect on "Report".

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{reportId:int}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteReport(int reportId)
{
    var success = await _reportService.DeleteReportControlAsync(reportId);
    if (success == false)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Messages");
        return RedirectToAction("EditReport");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("OK", "Messages");
    return RedirectToAction("Report");
}
```

In ASP.NET Core 1.0 (Full .NET Framework) I use the following attributes to save ModelState between methods. I took from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35987804/3878213

I recently switched to using asynchronous methods for controllers, services and repositories.
It seems to me that the attributes of action should also be asynchronous.
Initially, I rewrote the code attributes as follows:

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {    
            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            var modelState = controller?.ViewData.ModelState;
            if (modelState != null)
            {
                var listError = modelState.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors
                    .Select(s => s.ErrorMessage)
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s != null));
                var listErrorJson = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listError));
                controller.TempData["ModelState"] = listErrorJson;
            }
            await next();
        }
    }
public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        var tempData = controller?.TempData?.Keys;
        if (controller != null && tempData != null)
        {
            if (tempData.Contains("ModelState"))
            {
                var modelStateString = controller.TempData["ModelState"].ToString();
                var listError = await Task.Run(() => 
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(modelStateString));
                var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
                foreach (var item in listError)
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError(item.Key, item.Value ?? "");
                }

                controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
            }
        }
        await next();
    }
}
```

It seemed logical to me. But this code does not work as I expected.
But following asynchronous attributes are working properly:

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(filterContext, next);

            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            var modelState = controller?.ViewData.ModelState;
            if (modelState != null)
            {
                var listError = modelState.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors
                    .Select(s => s.ErrorMessage)
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s != null));
                var listErrorJson = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listError));
                controller.TempData["ModelState"] = listErrorJson;
            }
            await next();
        }
    }
public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(filterContext, next);

            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            var tempData = controller?.TempData?.Keys;
            if (controller != null && tempData != null)
            {
                if (tempData.Contains("ModelState"))
                {
                    var modelStateString = controller.TempData["ModelState"].ToString();
                    var listError = await Task.Run(() => 
                        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(modelStateString));
                    var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
                    foreach (var item in listError)
                    {
                        modelState.AddModelError(item.Key, item.Value ?? "");
                    }

                    controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
                }
            }
            await next();
        }
    }
```

Please tell me which of the two options more correct? And why does not work the first option?

Comment: Using `await next();` is incorrect here as it causes that method to be hit multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please tell me which of the two options more correct.

Option two is more correct, because it actually works - as you have noticed. If you were not intended to inherit from it, they would have made it `sealed`. Using the `ActionFilterAttribute` in this situation seems appropriate. In fact a [quick look @ the repo](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=org%3Aaspnet%20ActionFilterAttribute&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) reveals that this is actually a very common approach.

> Why does the first option not work?

It is not calling into the `base` invocations. The key is that there is likely code in the `base` calls that you're lacking in your custom implementation. Check it out [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ee2cfa1963ee7f8195130d41330f94d4622ca89a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Filters/ActionFilterAttribute.cs#L34-L53).