# TempData null in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to use TempData in asp.net core However I am getting a null value on the get method of TempData. Can anyone please let me know how can I use TempData in asp.net core

Below are the things I, have added as per the research.

**Project.json file**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "DataBase": "1.0.0-*",
    "UnitOfWork": "1.0.0-*",
    "ViewModel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Common": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**start.cs file**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession();
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddTransient<IMarketUOW, MarketUow>();
    services.AddTransient<ICategoryUow, CategoryUow>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserProfileUow, UserProfileUow>();
    services.AddTransient<IItemUow, ItemUow>();

    services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<EmakitiContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Here is the implementation of tempdata.When this method is called I can see the value in TempData.

```
[HttpGet("{pageNumber}")]
public GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> GetMarketList(int pageNumber)
{
    TempData["Currentpage"] = pageNumber;
    TempData.Keep("Currentpage");
    GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> genericResponseObject = new GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>>();
    genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
    genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_ConnectionFailed;
    try
    {
        var marketItem = _iMarketUow.GetMarketList(pageNumber);
        genericResponseObject.Data = marketItem.Item1;
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)marketItem.Item2 / (decimal)10);
        genericResponseObject.TotalPage = totalPages;
        genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = true;
        genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_SuccessMessageRecord;
        genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_ConnectionSuccess;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
        genericResponseObject.Message = exception.Message;
        genericResponseObject.ErrorCode = exception.HResult;
        genericResponseObject.ExceptionErrorMessage = exception.StackTrace;
    }
    return genericResponseObject;
}
```

But the below method has null value in the temp data.

```
[HttpPost]
public GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> AddUpdateMarket([FromBody] MarketViewModel marketViewModel)
{
    GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> genericResponseObject = new GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>>();
    genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
    genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_ConnectionFailed;

    if (marketViewModel!= null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _iMarketUow.AddUpdateMarketList(marketViewModel);
            genericResponseObject = GetMarketList(Convert.ToInt16(TempData.Peek("Currentpage")));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
            genericResponseObject.Message = exception.Message;
            genericResponseObject.ErrorCode = exception.HResult;
            genericResponseObject.ExceptionErrorMessage = exception.StackTrace;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_InputDataFormatNotMatch;
    }
    return genericResponseObject;
}
```

Here is the image of the debug session

[image: first request of http which hold the value to the tempdata]

[image: null value on the second request]

Comment: I had the same problem and I realized that was because of I was using private tab of the browser

Comment: For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tempdata

Answer (score 83):

Edited:

As Described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata-provider-and-session-state-cookies-arent-essential
by default TempData cookies are removed by the CookiePolicy Middleware. this can be changed by putting this in Startup.ConfigureServices():

```
// The TempData provider cookie is not essential. Make it essential
// so TempData is functional when tracking is disabled.
services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options => {
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

=============================================

Old Answer:

<strike>After Migrating to ASP Core 2.1 I had this issue and after working for a day find the solution:</strike>

in Startup.Configure()
`app.UseCookiePolicy();` should be  after `app.UseMVC();`

Comment: I think there is a lake of documentation here. I have created an issue about it: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8041

Comment: This was also the reason why recovery codes aren't shown when using ASP.NET Core Identity and you have 2 Factor Authentication enabled.

Comment: *Thank you for this!* This issue is made all the more confusing, because the session state docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for netcore 2.1 and 2.2 show `UseCookiePolicy()` being configured _before_ `UseMVC()`, which is evidently incorrect.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a day of research, I was having the same problem and just doing this fix it.

Comment: @Katstevens nothing's wrong with the order. check my answer below.

Comment: On ASP.NET Core 3.1 (not sure about 3, I tested on 3.1 only), you will need to add `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();` in `ConfigureServices` as well

Answer (score 47):

Nothing's wrong with middleware order as described on [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#order), which is:

1. Exception/error handling
2. HTTP Strict Transport Security Protocol
3. HTTPS redirection
4. Static file server
5. Cookie policy enforcement
6. Authentication
7. Session
8. MVC

But when we use Cookie policy enforcement (UseCookiePolicy), only **essential** cookie that will be sent to the browser and Cookie from Tempdata provider **is not essential** hence the problem. So we have to make it essential according to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata-provider-and-session-state-cookies-are-not-essential):

> The Tempdata provider cookie isn't essential. If tracking is disabled, the Tempdata provider isn't functional. To enable the Tempdata provider when tracking is disabled, mark the TempData cookie as essential in Startup.ConfigureServices

```
// The Tempdata provider cookie is not essential. Make it essential
// so Tempdata is functional when tracking is disabled.
services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options => {
   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Adding those lines should solve your issue without reordering middleware.

Comment: This is the right answer and should be used (not changing the order of services)

Comment: This is the 100% true and correct answer - I ended up deleting my tempdata cookie while debugging another issue and suddenly tempdata stopped working completely! An hour later I found this and now the issue is resolved.

Comment: After a couple hours of trying to figure out why Tempdata was null...this worked.

Comment: Thank you!. I Spent a significant amount of time debugging this issue.  Tempdata was working with vanilla return Views(), but any return RedirectToAction() calls would result in tempdata being empty.  This solved the issue ( .net core 3.1 )

Answer (score 20):

Please upgrade your all packages to same version `1.1.0` add caching service as well. Here is the required things for using `TempData` in `Asp.Net Core`

**Project.json**

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0"
```

**Here is the Startup.cs file. - ConfigureServices method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMemoryCache();
     services.AddSession();
     services.AddMvc();
}
```

**And Configure method.**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Now try with `TempData`, it will work.

And you can set the environment with set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development environment variable.

**PS**

`ASP.NET Core MVC` exposes the `TempData` property on a `Controller`. `TempData` can be used for storing transient data that only needs to be available for a single request after the current request.

When an object in a `TempDataDictionary` is read, it will be marked for deletion at the end of that request.

The `Peek` and `Keep` methods allow you to read the value without marking it for deletion. Say we get back to the first request where the value was saved to `TempData`.

With `Peek` you get the value without marking it for deletion with a single call.

```
//second request, PEEK value so it is not deleted at the end of the request
object value = TempData.Peek("value");

//third request, read value and mark it for deletion
object value = TempData["value"];
```

With `Keep` you specify a key that was marked for deletion that you want to keep. Retrieving the object and later on saving it from deletion are 2 different calls.

```
//second request, get value marking it from deletion
object value = TempData["value"];
//later on decide to keep it
TempData.Keep("value");

//third request, read value and mark it for deletion
object value = TempData["value"];
```

Comment: I am trying to use in the second http request.First method store the value to the tempdata and second request get the data from tempdata. However, I am getting the null value to get part

Comment: I tried it on my system while remove all authentication and other dependent code and it worked.

Comment: I added the full code .. on AddUpdateMarket() method I, am doing the second httpcall from angular 2. I can see the null value on the tempdata.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133607/discussion-between-ahmar-and-san-jaisy).

Comment: I have added the images for more info. Please have a look and let me know

Comment: Message me on chat.

Comment: I am with the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: @user1203003 you need to check your references packages versions.

Comment: I am have same issue with ASP.NET core 2.1 and installed "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0". However, TempData is always null

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you Peek was what i was after was no mention of it in the docs when i first heard about temp date