# TempData is always Null at ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, tempdata

I would like to use TempData in my .net core mvc application.
I followed the article from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tempdata

I always get NULL
Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(RentalsFilter filter)
{
    TempData["test"] = "ABC";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    var abc = TempData["test"].ToString();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is your operation step? If you access `Index` first, and then `Create`, will it be null? I fail to reproduce this issue, could you share us a project. Maybe, you could try `Session` to store the values.

Comment: Follow the instructions on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51740631/2572010)

Answer (score 8):

Had similar issue due to GDRP (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.1). If you want have it up and running without worring about GDPR you can just disable it. The config below also uses cookies (default) instead of session state for TempData.

**Startup.cs**

```
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

...

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy(); // <- this

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you configure TempData as said in the doc:

in ConfigureServices method add:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

services.AddSession();
```

And in Configure method you should add:

```
app.UseSession();
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer that worked for me (for asp.net Core 2.2) was

```
in Startup.Configure() app.UseCookiePolicy(); should be after app.UseMVC();
```

Which someone above has linked to  in the comments from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734039/tempdata-null-in-asp-net-core/51740631#51740631)

This is in addition to having

> app.UseSession() (in Configure)

and

> services.AddSession() (in ConfigureServices)

Answer (score 0):

please place

`@{TempData.Keep("test");}`

in your HTML file. 
It will persist for the next request.