# asp.net core 2.1 tempdata empty with redirecttoaction

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an asp.net core 2.1 project and I try to use TempData with RedirectToAction but it's always null (without Error)

Here is my ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        //services pour l'authentification
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        });


        //services pour session
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });

        //configuer port https
        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => options.HttpsPort = 443);

        Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;

        ManageDI(services);

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
    }
```

I have "app.UseSession();" in my Configure method

and here is my code

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task< IActionResult> ResetPassword(string query)
    {
        TempData["test"]= "test";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var b = TempData["test"];
        //b is always null when calling ResetPassword action

        var model = new Models.Account.LoginModel{
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

What did I forget please ?

Thanks

Comment: I finally found the answer : it's here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734039/tempdata-null-in-asp-net-core 
in Startup.Configure() app.UseCookiePolicy(); should be after app.UseMVC();

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what the issue is based on the code you've provided, but since you mention that it's null in your `ResetPassword` action from within your `Login` action, I'm assuming you're not properly persisting the value.

`TempData` is just that: temporary data. Once it's been accessed, it is removed. Therefore, when you set `b` here with its value, that's it - it's gone. If you then try to access it in another action later or even just in the view this action returns, it will be null now.

If you need to get the value, but also keep it around for later, you need to use `TempData.Peek`:

```
var b = TempData.Peek("test");
```