# Tempdata/sessions always null when using Response.Redirect in ASP.NET Core

Tags: session, asp.net-core-2.2, tempdata

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 in my project, in one of action method, I am storing data in tempdata and redirecting to SSO site for user validation. Later in MethodB which is callback method i get user details. But when am trying to get details from tempdata that i stored in MethodA, i get always null. Infact i tried with using sessions too but that is also getting null if i use Response.Redirect but works fine when i use RedirectToAction. Its seems Respose.Redirect is causing issue. Do anyone can suggest what could be issue and any possible solution?

```
    [TempData]
    public string Message1 { get; set; }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        TempData["Message2"] = "Some Value";

        Response.Redirect("SSOSite.com");
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        var message1 = Message1;
        var message2 = TempData["Message2"];
    }
```

Comment: Did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734039/tempdata-null-in-asp-net-core?

Comment: Yes, This problem occurs specifically when i use Response.Redirect otherwise its working perfectly when i use redirectoaction.