# Set TempData in ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to set TempData in View Component so that i can check it in Login Action when there is error in View Component.

Here is my .ts file code

```
window.onload = function () {

    fetch('../Controller/ActionName',
        {
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("Token")).value
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status != 200) {
                redirectToHomePage();
            }
            response.text().then((data) => {
                document.getElementById("Id")!.innerHTML = data;
            });
        });

    // Redirect to home page
    function redirectToHomePage() {
        var url = window.location.origin;
        window.location.href = url + '/Login/Login/';
    }
};
```

Below is the ViewComponent code

```
public IViewComponentResult TestViewComponent()
{
    try
    {
        // Do code here
    }
    Catch(Exception ex){                
         TempData["Error"] = "Err msg";
         return View(viewName)
    }

    return View(viewName);
}
```

TempData is set correctly in ViewComponent, but when response get back from .ts file from redirectToHomePage() function to Login/Login TempData will be null.

So how to get TempData in Login action

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813987/9695286

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a definition of ViewComponent.TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponent.tempdata?view=aspnetcore-3.1),And in the link you can see the TempData only have `get` method,So you cannot pass the TempData to `Login/Login`.