# Passing variables from httppost to the get

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I am trying to pass the birdRecords to the get part of the generateSearchResults inside my results controller but it does not go through.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult generateSearchResult([FromHeader] string data)
        {

            var birdRecords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<birdDataSolutionVM>(data);

            TempData["birds"] = birdRecords;

            return RedirectToAction("generateSearchResult");
        }

        public IActionResult generateSearchResult()
        {

            var a = TempData["birds"];

            return View();
        }
```

The problem is that the GET generateSearchResults is never being called. When I place a breakpoint inside the function it never pops up.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865208/397807

Comment: Why not return your View from the post?

Comment: Both are not working, when I am trying to return from post or get it does nothing