# How to preserve url when returning new View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

A beginner question - I have a HomeController, HomeModel and HomeView. When the user comes to the `http://page/Home` page, then `Index` method is executed and he can fill out some controls. After he clicks on a button (postback), the Process action is executed and in the case of an error, the application calls the `ModelState.AddModelError` method. Then the `Index` action is called again and I can display the error on the page.

This works OK, but the problem is that after the postback the new url is `http://page/Home/Index` instead of `http://page/Home`. Any idea how to prevent this?

PS - I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024227/113858) solution but then the new url was something like `http://page/Home?...long string of serialized ModelState data...`

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(MyModel model)
{
    if (...error...)
    {
        model.SetErrorState();
        ModelState.AddModelError("ProcessError", "error message");
        return View("Index", model);
    }
    else
    {
        // do something...
        model.SetSuccessState();
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're pushing to a new URL for the `HttpPost` action. If you change this to a `HttpPost` version of your `Home` Action you can neatly return to the page without the URL changing on error.

e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(ImportData model)
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, FormCollection data)
{
    if (...error...)
    {
        model.SetErrorState();
        ModelState.AddModelError("ProcessError", "error message");
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        // do something...
        model.SetSuccessState();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my question - both methods expect one parameter with the same type 'MyModel'. If I correct this and apply your solution, then the compiler complains 'Type HomeController already defines a member called Index with the same parameter types'.

Comment: updated @sventevit :) just add the (unused) `FormCollection` var to differentiate.

Comment: to @scgough - follow up question: how to do it when there are multiple buttons on the page and each should invoke own action? Then the action methods cannot all be named Index?

Comment: @sventevit I would use ajax (jquery) to POST the form data on each button press (rather than submitting the page as normal)