# session id changing in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i create an mvc3 razor test application and have admin area why session id change when from controller in default area i redirect to index to admin area,where change session id?

i get session id by this syntax in default controller and in admin area controller in their action Result method

i used this method in both controllers

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {

            string se = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;

        return view()
      }
```

how can i prevent to changing session id?

Comment: can you explain it more(please)

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/283341/1182982) it says.. "I've seen that happen even without MVC. If I remember correctly, ASP.NET keeps assigning new session ids until you place something into the Session variable."

Answer (score 4):

This is old but the simple answer to this is:

You have to store something in the Session, just add something in it to keep SessionID

For others Googling this :)